# Spring won't inject a JPARepository bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

**Dao**

```
@Repository
public interface LoginDao extends JpaRepository<Login, Integer> {
    Login findByLogin(String login);
}
```

**Validator**

```
@Component
public class PasswordChangeValidator implements Validator {

private LoginDao loginDao;

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {
    return PasswordChange.class.equals(aClass);
}

@Override
public void validate(Object o, Errors errors) {

    PasswordChange passwordChange = (PasswordChange) o;

            **// There is a null pointer here because loginDao is null** 
    Login login = loginDao.findByLogin(passwordChange.getLoginKey());


}

public LoginDao getLoginDao() {
    return loginDao;
}

@Autowired
public void setLoginDao(LoginDao loginDao) {
    **// There is a debug point on the next line and it's hit on server startup and I can
    // see the parameter us non-null** 
    this.loginDao = loginDao;
}
}
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("api")
public class PasswordController {

    @Autowired
    PasswordService passwordService;

    @InitBinder("passwordChange")
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder webDataBinder, WebRequest webRequest) {
        webDataBinder.setValidator(new PasswordChangeValidator());
    }   

    @RequestMapping(value = "/passwordChange", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody PasswordInfo passwordInfo(@RequestBody @Valid PasswordChange passwordChange)
            throws PasswordChangeException {
        return passwordService.changePassword(passwordChange.getLoginKey(), passwordChange.getOldPassword(), passwordChange.getNewPassword());
    }


}
```

I have the Dao listed above. This same dao bean gets injected in an @Service annotated class but not in @Component annotated Validator class. Well, not exactly the upon server startup I can see that the setter method gets called,  but when I try to use this variable in a method the variable shows as null.

Does anybody see a problem with my configuration ? Please note that the loginDao bean gets injected into a service class, so the Context configuration is good.

Comment: Where are you trying to use `PasswordChangeValidator`? Spring cannot inject `null`. You're probably creating the instance yourself.

Comment: Inside the controller method using `@Valid` annotation. I am binding the validator using the `@InitBinder` annotation inside the controller. I am not saying it is injecting null, just that the `loginDao` is null when it is not supposed to.

Comment: Show us that code with the `@InitBinder`.

Comment: Added the controller code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well there's your problem

```
webDataBinder.setValidator(new PasswordChangeValidator());
```

**Spring can only manage beans it created**. Here, you're creating the instance. Instead inject your bean into the `@Controller` and use it.

```
@Inject
private PasswordChangeValidator passwordChangeValidator;
...
webDataBinder.setValidator(passwordChangeValidator);
```

Comment: Bingo, right in front of my eyes, thanks for the help.